# Laravel Echo 'leaving()' not fired on window close

Tags: pusher, laravel-echo

So, I'm using Laravel Echo to broadcast/listen to Pusher events. 'listen()' and 'here()' are working fine, but 'joining()' and 'leaving()' are never fired.

Has anyone encountered this before? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

```
    window.Echo.join('account_'+this.props.account.id)
        .joining((user) => {
            console.log('joining');
        })
        .here(user => {
            console.log('here');
            this.props.setOnlineStatus(this.props.userData, true);
        })
        .leaving(user => {
            alert('leaving');
            this.props.setOnlineStatus(this.props.userData, false);
        })
        .listen('ChatMessageSent', (e) => {
            if(e.users.find(user => {
                return user.id == this.props.userData.id
            })){
                dispatch({
                    type: MESSAGE_SENT,
                    message: e.message
                });
            }
        })
```